# Custom Post Type - Display Categories & Tags In Dashboard list

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type of business.  When viewing the business list from the dashboard, I would like the categories and tags for the business to be displayed just like with typical posts (see screenshot below).

here is what I have for creating the business post type and it's custom taxonomy

```
       add_action( 'init', 'create_business_category_tax' );

        function create_business_category_tax() {
            register_taxonomy(
                'business_category',
                'business',
                array(
                    'label' => __( 'Business Category' ),
                    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'business_category' ),
                    'hierarchical' => true,
                )
            );
        }

        function signal_post_type_business() {

            $supports = array(
            'title', // post title
            'editor', // post content
            'author', // post author
            'thumbnail', // featured images
            'excerpt', // post excerpt
            'custom-fields', // custom fields
            'comments', // post comments
            'revisions', // post revisions
            'post-formats', // post formats
            );

            $labels = array(
                'name' => _x('Businesses', 'plural'),
                'singular_name' => _x('Business', 'singular'),
                'menu_name' => _x('Businesses', 'admin menu'),
                'name_admin_bar' => _x('Businesses', 'admin bar'),
                'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'add new'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Business'),
                'new_item' => __('New Business'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Business'),
                'view_item' => __('View Businesses'),
                'all_items' => __('All Businesses'),
                'search_items' => __('Search Businesses'),
                'not_found' => __('No Businesses found.'),
            );

            $args = array(
                'supports' => $supports,
                'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-store',
                'labels' => $labels,
                'public' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'business'),
                'has_archive' => true,
                'hierarchical' => false,
            );
            register_post_type('business', $args);
        }
        add_action('init', 'signal_post_type_business');
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In your $args array of the taxonomy add this line:

```
'show_admin_column' => true,
```

that will add it to the admin edit screen